# SQLite_check constraint, which checks that the entered year is at least this year

Tags: sqlite, constraints

```
P_Year int default 2022 Check (P_Year >= select strftime('%Y','now'))
```

I want to check constraint on p_year, which checks that the entered year is at least the current year. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code and have you already tried it yet?

Comment: Sure, I tried it! I think, the problem is the part, where I call the current year.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the `SELECT` keyword which is invalid inside the check constraint.

If `P_Year`'s data type is `TEXT` use this:

```
CHECK (P_Year >= strftime('%Y','now'))
```

If its data type is `INTEGER` (as it should be) you must convert the result of `strftime()` to an integer because it returns a string:

```
CHECK (P_Year >= strftime('%Y','now') + 0)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=da3bf51b217d14a572781109671d6776).